# Compare two input dates with another two dates in the table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

i want to filter the records between two dates(`FROM_DATE` & `TO_DATE`) by two dates input(@frm_dt & @to_dt),if i give the two dates(@frm_dt & @to_dt) as a two inputs i want to filter the records depends on the available date between `FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE`.
i have struck in that condition more than a one weeks.
i am little poor in English communication.kindly help me.

```
FROM_DATE        TO_DATE
2017-01-02 .    2017-06-30 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-09-30 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-12-31 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-10-31 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-11-30 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-10-31 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-09-29 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-12-31 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-08-31 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-11-30 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-10-31 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-10-30 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-09-30 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-09-30 .
```

if i give the @frm_dt as 2017-01-01 & to_dt as 2017-06-30,it should returns all the recorde because these two dates are between that `FROM_DATE` & `TWO_DATE`.
similarly if i give the @frm_dt as 2017-10-31 & to_dt as 2017-12-25.it should only returns below dates

```
FROM_DATE        TO_DATE
2017-01-02 .    2017-12-31 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-10-31 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-11-30 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-10-31 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-12-31 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-11-30 .
2017-01-02 .    2017-10-31 .
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you must decide if you want: a) all records that overlap to the two input dates, or b) all records that are comprise in the two input dates. Accordingly with your decision you shuld set yor `WHERE` condition:

a)
`WHERE yourTable.FromDate <= @DATE_TO and yourTable.ToDate >= @DATE_FROM`.

b)
`WHERE yourTable.FromDate >= @DATE_FROM and yourTable.ToDate <= @DATE_TO`.

Hope this help

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

**Just execute this query in your database and you will get the output.**

```
  Create procedure ReturnDates(
  @fromDate datetime,
  @todate datetime
 )
  AS BEGIn
 Select From_dt ,TO_DT
 from tablename
 WHERE FROM_DT >= @fromDate and TO_DT  <= @todate 
 END
 GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this condition:

```
WHERE CAST(FROM_DATE AS DATETIME) >= CAST(@frm_dt AS DATETIME) AND
CAST(TO_DATE AS DATETIME) <= CAST(@to_dt AS DATETIME)
```

Or you can use this condition:

```
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), FROM_DATE, 121) >= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @frm_dt, 121) AND
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TO_DATE, 121) <= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @to_dt, 121)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check [check W3SCHOOL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)! here.
i think you try INBETWEEN AND BETWEEN.